# Send emails in laravel from a web server

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel project that I need to send emails to, and it works on localhost, but when I upload it to a web server it doesn't work. Where's my mistake?
[image]

Controller:

```
class merluzaController extends Controller
{
    public function mail(request $request){
        $datos=[
            "nombre"=>$request->nombre,
            "apellido"=>$request->apellido,
            "correo"=>$request->correoE,
            "numeroT"=>$request->numeroT,
            "mensaje"=>$request->mensaje,
        ];
        Mail::send('emails.mails', $datos, function ($message) {
            $message->to("ltomicb@gmail.com", "Lucas")->subject('Página de MerluzaDePincho');

        });
        Session::flash('mensaje_enviado','Mensaje enviado correctamente.');
        return redirect('/contacto');
    }
}
```

ENV:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=postmaster@sandbox8f7345b6f0f14762871d8489a6a672c9.mailgun.org
MAIL_PASSWORD=****************
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=merluzadepincho@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Merluza de Pincho"
```

Comment: Change `APP_DEBUG=true` and show the error

Comment: OK, ready. "Class 'Illuminate\Support\facades\Mail' not found". I don't know which is the mistake.

Comment: Since it's a facade, just add this to the top of the class :

`use Mail;`

Comment: I have already added it, if I hadn't it wouldn't work in Localhost neither

Comment: add use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail; before class definition

Comment: Yes, I have already done it, it still don't work

Answer (score 0):

if the problem is "Class 'Illuminate\Support\facades\Mail' not found then you have to import it

you can try to use

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
```

or you can try

```
\Mail::send('emails.mails', $datos, function ($message) {
            $message->to("ltomicb@gmail.com", "Lucas")->subject('Página de MerluzaDePincho');

        });
```

instead of

```
Mail::send('emails.mails', $datos, function ($message) {
    $message->to("ltomicb@gmail.com", "Lucas")->subject('Página de MerluzaDePincho');

});
```

as `\Mail::send()` doesn't need to be imported

you can check this [article](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/method-to-not-found-in-illuminatesupportfacadesmail) you can find here some good answers

if nothing of this works then you need to verify that guzzle package is configured correctly and its version is 6 higher and look into your server php modules and compare them to your dev modules `php -m` should list them all

finally reach out to your hosting company and explain the issue for them as some companies block this kind of callbacks for security reasons or to force the user to purchase a premium account or something like that

hope this helps.

Comment: Right, I have already solved it, but now It says "Connection could not be established with host smtp.mailgun.org :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to smtp.mailgun.org:21 (Connection timed out)". What is the problem?

Comment: well i guess this problem isn't from laravel it is because your host provider blocks inbound calls i did some researches and it appears that it is one of two things 1- you have wrong configuration in you .env file but you said it worked on dev so that it is not an option, 2 - your hosting provider is blocking the connection between your server and mailgun server

Comment: maybe try setting the encryption to tls  MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls